# Solving Postfix Notation Equations c++

Tags: c++

For my output I am getting an invalid allocation error. Here is the edited code from the comments. The only edit I did not make is the change to the "top" function using the assertion macro, this is because it is undefined to my compiler. Thank you so very much for all the help, I see the light! I just need to clear the invalid allocation error, the compiler points to the push function when I break it during debugging.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void solvePostfix(string postfixStr);

class OperandStack
{
private:
    double * s;  //pointer to 1D dynamic array for storing stack elements
    int capacity,  //stack capacity
        t;  //index of the top element on stack
    void growStack(int newCapacity);  //increases the stack if it is full
                        //must be called from the push function if the stack is full

 public:
    OperandStack(){ capacity = 1; s = NULL; t = -1; };
     OperandStack(int capacity);
     ~OperandStack();
     int size() const;  //return the number of elements in the stack
     bool isFull() const; 
     bool isEmpty() const;
     double top() const;  //returns the element at the top of the stack
                 //without removing it from the stack
     void push(double x);
     void pop();

};

OperandStack :: OperandStack(int capacity)
{ 
    capacity = capacity;
    s = new double [capacity];
    t = -1;
}

OperandStack :: ~OperandStack()
{
    while(this->isEmpty() == false)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++)
        {
            this->pop();     
        }
    }
    delete []s;
}

int OperandStack :: size () const
{

    return t+1;
}

bool OperandStack :: isFull() const
{
    return this->size() == capacity;

}

bool OperandStack :: isEmpty() const
{
    if(t == -1) return true;
    else return false;
}

double OperandStack :: top() const
{
    if(this->isEmpty() == false) return s[t];

}


void OperandStack :: push( double x) 
{
    if(this->isFull())
    {
        this->growStack(capacity+(capacity/2));
    }

    else if(this->isEmpty())
    { 
        t = 0; 
        s[t] = x;
    }
    else
    {
        ++t;
        s[t] = x;
    }
}

void OperandStack :: pop()
{
    s[t] = NULL;
    t--;
}

void OperandStack :: growStack(int newCapacity)
{
    double *copyStack = new double[newCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) //Deep copy 
    {
        copyStack[i] = s[i];
    }

    if(s != NULL) delete[] s;
    s = copyStack;
    capacity = newCapacity;
}


void solvePostfix(string postfixStr)
{   
    int i = 0; //The index of a number in the string
    double x, y; //Represent the numbers from the string
    char symbol; //The operator from the string
    OperandStack tempStack;

    while(i < postfixStr.length())
    {
        if(postfixStr[i] >= '0' && postfixStr[i] <= '9')
        {
            tempStack.push(postfixStr[i]-'0');
        }
        else if(postfixStr[i] == '+' || postfixStr[i] == '-'  
            || postfixStr[i] == '*' || postfixStr[i] == '/')
        {
            y = tempStack.top();
            tempStack.pop();
            x = tempStack.top();
            tempStack.pop();
            switch(postfixStr[i])
            {
                case '+': tempStack.push(x + y); break;
                case '-': tempStack.push(x - y); break;
                case '/': tempStack.push(x / y); break;
                case '*': tempStack.push(x * y); break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "error- malformed expression.";
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Result: " << tempStack.top() << endl;

}




int main()
{
    OperandStack myStack(8);
    string inputPostfixStr;

    cout << "Enter a postfix expression: ";
    std::getline(cin, inputPostfixStr);

    solvePostfix(inputPostfixStr);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output `1.#IND` stands for [Positive indefinite NaN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx). I haven't looked at your code to figure out why this happens.

Comment: @R SahuThank you, so basically it means negative infinity?

Comment: No. Negative infinity would be output like `-1.#INF`. 1/0 -> infinity. 0/0 -> indefinite.

Comment: Not it means that you made an illegal operation (like infinity/infinity) and so the result was NaN. The NaN can have a value that can tell you what kind of wrong operation happened though.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand that. But what is going wrong then? It's probably inside of the void solvePostfix(string postfixStr). I'm not looking for just the answer to get the grade, I am genuinely confused on what is causing this error, I have been working at it all day haha.

Comment: @meneldal Thank you for that edit! That was from clearing out some of my comments to slim the code down. The error is the same.

Comment: I just edited so that the code would compile (minus the system-specific `stdfax.h` and `system`)

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. In your default constructor, you are initializing `capacity` to `0`. And then, you are you using the following statement to increase the size.

   ```
   this->growStack(capacity+(capacity/2));
   ```

   Since `capacity` is initialized to `0`, you never really grow the size.

   A simple fix to this problem is to start with an initial capacity of `1`, or change the logic in the call to `growStack`.

   That is the main problem that's causing you to access memory that you are not supposed to be able access. Undefined behavior ensues as a result.
2. You have couple of functions that don't have a `return` statement in all the paths.

   ```
   bool OperandStack :: isFull() const
   {
      if(this->size() == capacity) return true;
      else if(this->size() != capacity) return false;
   }
   ```

   can be fixed by using:

   ```
   bool OperandStack :: isFull() const
   {
      return (this->size() == capacity);
   }
   ```

   And

   ```
   double OperandStack :: top() const
   {
      if(this->isEmpty() == false) return s[t];
   }
   ```

   can be fixed by using:

   ```
   double OperandStack :: top() const
   {
      assert(this->isEmpty() == false);
      return s[t];
   }
   ```
3. You are using the wrong argument in the calls to `push`.

   ```
    tempStack.push(postfixStr[i]);
   ```

   should be:

   ```
    tempStack.push(postfixStr[i]-'0');
   ```
4. The code to read the expression in string form is not right.

   ```
    cin >> inputPostfixStr;
   ```

   will stop reading input when it encounters a whitespace. When your input is "1 1 +", after that line is executed, the value of `inputPostfixStr` will be `"1"`. Change that line to:

   ```
   std::getline(cin, inputPostfixStr);
   ```
5. The implementation of `OperandStack(int capacity)` not right.

   ```
   OperandStack :: OperandStack(int capacity)
   { 
       capacity = capacity;
       s = new double [capacity];
       t = -1;
   }
   ```

   You have two variables named `capacity` -- the argument to the function and member variable of the class. However, inside the function, the member function shadows the member variable. As a consequence, the member variable is not initialized. If you end up using this constructor, you will run into undefined behavior.

   Change the line

   ```
       capacity = capacity;
   ```

   to

   ```
       this->capacity = capacity;
   ```
6. The `if-else` logic in `push` is not correct.

   ```
   void OperandStack :: push( double x) 
   {
       if(this->isFull())
       {
           // this->growStack(capacity+(capacity/2));
           // This will be a problem if the initial size is zero or 1
           // 1/2 == 0. Change it appropriately.
       }

       // Using the `else` here is a problem.
       // If you do, when the stack is full, the stack is grown but 
       // nothing is added to the stack.
       // else if(this->isEmpty())

       if(this->isEmpty())
       { 
           t = 0; 
           s[t] = x;
       }
       else
       {
           ++t;
           s[t] = x;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! What does the assert function do for the top function?

Comment: Please note that if you actually use this kind of push, it still works only if your number has one digit.

Comment: @music.surrounds, `assert` is a macro that will stop the program if the the expression in the argument doesn't evaluate to true. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert for more details.

Comment: Also, using your code exactly gives me an invalid allocation error and assert is not able to be used, it is underlined in red and says it is undefined.

Comment: @meneldal The push I wrote is only for one digit numbers. That is what is asked for by the assignment.

Comment: @music.surrounds, I added a bit more to the answer -- about reading the input data.

Comment: @R Sahu I am currently getting the error : Unhandled exception at 0x00031ba5 in Assignment 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000. with the added changes minus the change to top.

Comment: @R Sahu I made the change to push and changed this->growStack(capacity+(capacity/2)) to this->growStack(capacity*2). I also removed 'else' from 'else if' in the second statement of push. However I still recieved the same invalid allocation error, even when the initial capacity is initialized to 1

Comment: @R Sahu This is my output log : First-chance exception at 0x00e91b9a in Assignment 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x00e91b9a in Assignment 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: @music.surrounds, hopefully you take my working program and figure out where the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the way you're putting data in your stack

```
        if(postfixStr[i] >= '0' && postfixStr[i] <= '9')
        {
            tempStack.push(postfixStr[i]);
        }
```

A compiler should have given you a warning for this. `postfixStr[i]` is a `char` and it makes no sense to convert it implicitly to `double`. This is why you are getting completely wrong values for x and y (and in the end bad results).

Comment: I am not getting that warning, but I can see how that's an issue. I'm not sure how to convert the input any other way though.

Comment: either a string stream or a sscanf would do the trick (for more than one character, for just one character you might as well just use basic ASCII arithmetic

Comment: Could you help me with this invalid allocation error please? It happens when I change the capacity from 0 to 1. When capacity is 0, then I get NaN. When capacity starts at 1, I get the error.

Comment: Also, I have tried looking in my books and online, but I'm not sure I quite understand how to implement ASCII arithmetic in this situation.

Comment: I meant to use what was in the other (and better) answer: `postfixStr[i]-'0'`